# (Magento2) knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

On page loading the following error occurs.

> knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding
>   "attr: function (){return {
>                              id:'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty','data-cart-item':item_id,'data-item-qty':qty,'data-cart-item-id':product_sku}
>   }" Message: product_sku is not defined

**Also on cart updation:**

> knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding
>   "foreach: function (){return
>   $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return
>   {name:getTemplate(),data:item,afterRender:function(){$parents[1].initSidebar()}}
>   }" Message: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {
>                              id:'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty','data-cart-item':item_id,'data-item-qty':qty,'data-cart-item-id':product_sku}
>   }" Message: product_sku is not defined

This error occurs only in new custom themes, and works fine in default Magento and Luma themes.